# add action handler to button in cell in ios6 using [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:]

Tags: ios, objective-c

In ios6, 
[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:] always return a cell.
So what if I want to add some button handler on my cell, and avoiding adding the target each time the cell is reused.

For now, I use tag to memorize is the cell has already been hook up:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCell";
    MyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(!cell.tag){
        cell.tag = 1;
        [cell.playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playInputClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Any better solution (not using registerClass or registerNib).

Any suggestions appreciated,

Hugues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add it again.  The button automatically eliminates duplicate target/action pairs.  If you do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    [cell.playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playInputClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

… you will find that you only receive `playInputClicked:` once per tap, not 100 times.

Comment: sorry for the super long delay (just 2y...). not sure how I miss the notice... thx!